# Having Error inserting JSON data into GridDB using Python

Tags: python, json, griddb

I am working on integrating GridDB with JSON data in Python. I have a JSON file that I want to insert into a GridDB table using the GridDB Python client. However, I am encountering an error while trying to perform the insertion.

```
from griddb_python import GridDBFactory

factory = GridDBFactory()
gridstore = factory.get_gridstore(host='localhost', port=10001, cluster_name='myCluster', username='admin', password='admin')
con_info = factory.get_container_info("myContainer")

json_file = "path/to/my_json_file.json"

with open(json_file, 'r') as file:
    json_data = file.read()

container = con_info.container
container.put(json_data)
```

```
griddb_python.GSException: Error occurred in function gsPutContainerRows() - RC_INVALID_ARGUMENT : Invalid argument specified
```

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this error.Thanks